# Why does logistic regression not have variance, but have deviance?

Tags: regression, logistic

[In this blog](https://advstats.psychstat.org/book/logistic/index.php) of Section 5.2, the author said:

> For the linear regression, we evaluate the overall model fit by
>   looking at the variance explained by all the predictors. For the
>   logistic regression, we cannot calculate a **variance**. However, we can
>   define and evaluate the **deviance** instead.

Why the logistic model cannot calculate the "variance"? The dependent variable has already been logit transformed, and becomes a continuous variable from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Why does it different from the "regular linear regression", as is written is Section 2:

> **Different from** the regular linear regression, no residual is used in
>   the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused, and really need to read a good elementary introduction to logistic regression (or generalized linear models). On this site, you could start with [Interpretation of coefficients in logistic regression output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219828/interpretation-of-coefficients-in-logistic-regression-output)  and  [Understanding R output in Logistic Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96236/understanding-r-output-in-logistic-regression).

In short, sums of squares in normal-distribution based linear regression is (a transformation of) log likelihoods, but in generalized linear regression models (glm's) such as logistic regression, log likelihood can take very different forms. I take it that with *variance* you refer to these various sums-of-squares. Deviance is a generalization (replacement) for these used in glm's. For the details you need to read a good intro or tutorial.